# Nullish Coalescing is not working in this case

Tags: typescript, nullish-coalescing

In the following code I want to print out the "dayNumber" property, in case the item is an object otherwise It should print out the number 0.
I can't get rid of the error and I don't understand why.

[image: code with error]

I'm trying to use the nullish coalescing operator, which seams appropriate in this case.

Comment: Please DO NOT post images, post code

Answer (score 2):

The nullish coalescing operator DOES NOT apply to this case:

> The nullish coalescing (??) operator is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

In this case you have a simple union of type `Day | 0`, you just have to check manually:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const item = daysArray[i];

  if (typeof item === "number") {
    console.log(0);
  } else {
    console.log(item.dayNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I get it, thank you very much. Isn't there a more coincise way though?

Comment: @CristianCassetta well, you could do `console.log(typeof item === "number" ? ' : item.dayNumber);`

Answer (score 1):

The nullish coalescing does not apply in this case, here is documentation of nullish coalescing with examples of how it's supposed to be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

The reason why your code is giving red squiggly is because the element at `daysArray[i]` might be either a number or an object which has the shape of the `Day` interface. so trying to access `daysArray[i].dayNumber` is not entirely correct, first you have to check that it's an object and not a number. this way typescript compiler will infer the type of `daysArray[i]` to be of type `Day` and will allow you to access `dayNumber` property.

Here is a working example:

```js
type Day = {
  dayNumber: number;
  color: string;
  isBooked: boolean;
};

const myDay: Day = {
  dayNumber: 12,
  color: "blue",
  isBooked: false
};

const daysArray: (Day | 0)[] = [0, 0, 0, myDay];

for (let i = 0; i < daysArray.length; i++) {
  const element = daysArray[i];
  if(typeof element === 'object') {
    console.log(element.dayNumber);
  }
}
```

Please refer to the official documentation for type narrowing: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much!! Something is still not clear though.
From MDN:  __"The nullish coalescing operator treats undefined and null as specific values. So does the optional chaining operator (?.), which is useful to access a property of an object which may be null or undefined. Combining them, you can safely access a property of an object which may be nullish and provide a default value if it is."__
So, this " daysArray[i]?.dayNumber ?? 0 " should work...but it doesn't.

Comment: @CristianCassetta the `?.` operator applies to unions of type `T | null | undefined`. Again, this is not your case since `daysArray[i]` is of type `Day | 0`

Comment: if a variable (in your case `daysArray[i]` ) were of type: `object | null`, or the type were `object | undefined`, or the type were `object | null | undefined`, in these cases you would use optional chaining, but the variable type in your case is: `object | 0` and here lies the problem, you cannot chain into a number.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the hang of it. Thanks everybody, really great community.

Answer (score 0):

Because typescript is a safety type and uses Type Guards to prevent you from calling a parameter don't declare it, so you can't call `dayNumber` when the type is Literal `0` the **nullish coalescing** and **Optional Chaining** use it when the parameter/property is **declare** as optional in TypeScript and The onion of type `0` and `Day` doesn't have this property (but in JS you can do it because don't have types to compile check it and complain), so for solve the problem you must use type guards technics (in, instanceof, ..etc) it makes more code, or declare the array as `any[]` and escape from type checking

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
console.log((daysArray[i] as Day).dayNumber ?? 0);
```